# Rigify - How do I change 'Bend Rotation Axis' parameter using Python?

Tags: python, scripting, rigify

I’m trying to change this 'Bend Rotation Axis' parameter using Python: *Bone Tab > Rigify Type > Bend Rotation Axis*. Unfortunately, the output of the Info window isn’t shedding much light on this:

[image]

I have tried this:

```
 bpy.data.objects['metarig'].pose.bones['thumb.01.L'].primary_rotation_axis = 'X'
```

... but I’m getting the following error:

> AttributeError: 'PoseBone' object has no attribute 'primary_rotation_axis'

When I hover over the Bend rotation axis dropdown, I get the following tooltip:

[image]

**Q:** How do I access the Rigify parameters class and assign my values?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
 bpy.data.objects['metarig'].pose.bones['thumb.01.L'].rigify_parameters.roll_alignment = 'manual'
 bpy.data.objects['metarig'].pose.bones['thumb.01.L'].rigify_parameters.copy_rotation_axes = [True, False, False]
```